# Trying to run Angular unit tests. They were working fine but suddenly, they break with a weird issue

Tags: angular

The following error occurs:

```
HeadlessChrome 80.0.3987 (Mac OS X 10.15.3) ERROR
  An error was thrown in afterAll
  ReferenceError: require is not defined
      at node_modules/canonical-path/index.spec.js:1:12
  ReferenceError: require is not defined
      at node_modules/istanbul-instrumenter-loader/node_modules/json-schema-traverse/spec/index.spec.js:3:16
  ReferenceError: require is not defined
      at node_modules/json-schema-traverse/spec/index.spec.js:3:16
  ReferenceError: require is not defined
      at node_modules/karma-chrome-launcher/test/jsflags.spec.js:3:14
  ReferenceError: exports is not defined
      at node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/schematics/ng-add/index.spec.js:9:23
HeadlessChrome 80.0.3987 (Mac OS X 10.15.3): Executed 37 of 39 (skipped 2) ERROR (0 secs / 1.223 secs)
HeadlessChrome 80.0.3987 (Mac OS X 10.15.3) ERROR
  An error was thrown in afterAll
  ReferenceError: require is not defined
      at node_modules/canonical-path/index.spec.js:1:12
  ReferenceError: require is not defined
      at node_modules/istanbul-instrumenter-loader/node_modules/json-schema-traverse/spec/index.spec.js:3:16
  ReferenceError: require is not defined
      at node_modules/json-schema-traverse/spec/index.spec.js:3:16
  ReferenceError: require is not defined
      at node_modules/karma-chrome-launcher/test/jsflags.spec.js:3:14
  ReferenceError: exports is not defined
HeadlessChrome 80.0.3987 (Mac OS X 10.15.3): Executed 37 of 39 (skipped 2) ERROR (1.368 secs / 1.223 secs)
```

Comment: Did you check `index.spec.js:` on line 1?

Comment: Couldn't find the file

Comment: What node version are you using?

Comment: Node Version - v13.8.0. But I have been using this before the error popped up.

Comment: What did you do prior to this happening? What was the change that caused this to start happening?